# Using the Decorator pattern to add public methods to an object

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented

The Decorator pattern is usually used to extend the functionality of an object by extending one of it's current methods.

To illustrate, please consider an object `object` and a decorator `decorator`. `object` has one method called `methodA()`. `decorator`, because we're in the Decorator pattern, also has this method by inheritance (both `object` and `decorator` eventually inherit from the same super-class which has `methodA()`. Let's call it `AbstractObject`).

`methodA()` in `object` looks like this:

```
public void methodA(){
    // do stuff
}
```

`methodA()` in `decorator` looks like this:

```
public void methodA(){
    // do some extra stuff.
    wrappedObject.methodA(); // and then delegate to the wrapped object.
}
```

It would be used like this:

```
AbstractObject object = new ConcreteObject();
object.methodA(); // does stuff
object = new ConcreteDecorator(object);
object.methodA(); // does stuff and some more stuff. the extended methodA().
```

The point of `decorator` is to extend the functionality of `object`, **and it does this by extending one of `object`'s current methods**. So far, classic Decorator.

**Now, my question:**

As I said Decorator usually extends an object's functionality by adding content to one of the object's current methods.

But what if I wanted to use Decorator to **add public methods to an object**?

Please consider the following scenario where `decorator` has another method `methodB()`:

```
AbstractObject object = new ConcreteObject();
object.methodA(); // does stuff
object = new ConcreteDecorator(object);
((ConcreteDecorator)object).methodB();
// methodB() belongs to ConcreteDecorator() but not to AbstractObject().
```

As you see if I wanted to do this, I would have to cast `object` to `ConcreteDecorator`.

This exposes the concrete type of `object` and the fact that it's decorated, and as such somewhat defeats the intent of the Decorator pattern. Also, the code invoking `methodB()` would have to know `object` is decorated. Again, not very much in the spirit of Decorator.

**In light of this I have two questions:**

- Is the Decorator pattern ever used this way? Is it ever used to add
  public methods to an object, as opposed to only 'extending' it's
  current methods?
- Are there situations where this would be a good idea or a wise use of
  Decorator?

Answer (score 11):

The decorator pattern is typically used to avoid an explosion of subclasses.  A common example involves UI windows that you may want to have any combination of n attributes (scrollbar, titlebar, resizable, movable, etc.).
Supporting all combinations of all those `N` attributes for all UI windows `M` subclasses would involve making `N * M` subclasses.

The decorator pattern prevents the explosion by wrapping around the base window class' **existing** public methods.
The decorator pattern ideally would only require `N + M` classes in this case.

For the case you have described, you are adding **new** public methods; therefore, the decorator pattern probably is not ideal.  I cannot think of any situations where it would be ideal to add new methods via a decorator.

A few alternatives to consider:

### Subtyping

It is valid to use subtyping to add methods, provided you are keeping the SOLID principles in mind.  Therefore, you might consider extending the concrete object to support methodB and then design the decorator around it.

```
AbstractObject object = new ExtendedConcreteObject();
object.methodA(); // does stuff
object = new ConcreteDecorator(object);
(ConcreteDecorator)object.methodB();
// methodB() belongs to ExtendedConcreteObject() but not to AbstractObject()
```

### Adapter Pattern

Another way to view the problem:  by adding a public method, you are changing the object's interface.  This can be done by using the [adapter](http://www.oodesign.com/adapter-pattern.html) pattern.  To keep the concrete decorator simple, you might consider creating a [decorator](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html) and then building an adapter for that decorator.

```
AbstractObject object = new ConcreteObject();
object.methodA(); // does stuff
object = new ConcreteDecorator(object);
object = new ConcreteAdapter(object);
(ConcreteAdapter)object.methodB();
// methodB() belongs to ConcreteAdapter() but not to AbstractObject() or ConcreteDecorator().
```

Answer (score 0):

Decoration is about adding subtle behavioural changes to an underlying class.

I think your intention is to actually Extend a class. Think "Separation of Concerns".  Also, the "Open/Closed" principle springs to mind (which I personally don't entirely agree with)

The point of decoration is that you pass an object around which supports a given interface.  If you're doing extra stuff in extra methods, then your application will need to "down-cast" that object to get the extra behavior.

Downcasting to some engineers seems okay, while other engineers feel this isn't a clean solution as code is littered with instanceof keywords.   This ties classes to your extended implemetation which requires more diligence when refactoring.

Personally, downcasting of objects should be used sparingly, and should be hidden as much as possible from consuming classes, as it breaks an interface.

All I am saying is it really is a subjective question.  Be careful.